# Magento 2 Webhook Extension

Tags: magento2, sales-order, notification

What appears to be commonplace and easy to do on just about every other platform, Im trying to source an extension that allows for order notifications via webhooks...

I've looked high and low but cant seem to find an extensions / app that allows for posting of order data to a remote endpoint without having to resort to writing my own extension / observer.

Can anyone recommend either paid or free extension that I can install and simply get transaction data posted to a remote endpoint?

thanks in advance

Comment: You could also use the API to retrieve that data - but if you need a webhook notification then you'll need to go one of those other platforms.

Comment: You could also copy yourself in the email notification.

Comment: are you suggesting that either setup a polling request externally every few minutes to check for new orders or develop something internally inside the specific Magento account?

Answer (score 0):

I found this extension, I haven't tried it yet though.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-webhook